# Generate double including 1 in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, algorithm, dart, random

I've been asked a question how to add `1` in range for `random.nextDouble()`. The solution I came up with was generating int and applying it to decimals.

```
  double getRandomDouble(){
    final random = Random();

    int a = random.nextInt(10001); // generates int from 0 to 10000
    String stringValue;
    if (a == 10000) {
      stringValue = '1.0';
    } else {
      stringValue = '0.$a';
    }
    return double.parse(stringValue);
  }
```

Comment: the reason why this solution isn't correct is because if `a` is for example 2, 20, 200, or 2000 it will result in the same double. If you padded them with 0 in the left I think this solution would be fine as well, so like `stringValue = '0.${a.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}';`, but yeah your answer is better

Answer (score 1):

I've been told a solution for that is `random.nextInt(256)/255` or `random.nextInt(intMax)/intMax`